# Asset filtered out and will not be served: add `config.assets.precompile

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I just migrated my Application to rails `4.1.0` from `4.1.rc2`.  Started getting these errors for my JS files

```
ActionView::Template::Error: Asset filtered out and will not be served: add `config.assets.precompile += %w( my_js )` to `config/application.rb` and restart your server
```

Comment: Welcome to the 1,500 reputation level!  You can now create tags now, even if by accident.  Please *always* be sure to select from the autocomplete menu!

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Responding to urging from Heroku, the Rails maintainers have merged sanity checks from the sprockets_better_errors gem into Rails 4.1. See https://github.com/rails/sprockets-rails/pull/84

The intent is to reveal asset pipeline errors that you would see in production when you run the app in development mode.

You probably are using a `javascript_include_tag` in an application layout instead of placing your JavaScript files in the *app/assets/javascripts/* folder.

You could move your files to the *app/assets/javascripts/* folder.

Alternatively, you'll need to update your *config/application.rb* file to include:

```
config.assets.precompile += %w( my_js )
```

Note that the filename should not include the .js file extension.

Comment: That's not a good reason. Not everybody uses Heroku and this really caused me problems. We should NOT have to precompile our custom .js or .css files in development. That's part of the reason why we have a development mode in the first place.

Comment: Can't you just add the js file to the asset pipeline like so://= require modernizr

Comment: do you not need the file extension? `my_js` would be the name of `my_js.js`?

I thought you could use the manifest. why would you do `config.assets.precompile += %w( my_js )`when you can list it in the manifest?

Comment: My JS files are already in the app/assets/javascripts folder, and I still get the same error, when I try to javascript_include_tag that same file.

Comment: @Qasim - I have actually had to restort to inline-js to deal with this 'feature' (cough), in some cases. Why load a huge piece of JS for 'everybody' which is only used on one unfrequently used page?  Note that this also breaks some gems, so you may need to add config.assets.precompile statements for those folders.

Answer (score 33):

If you have added something like `stylesheet_link_tag params[:controller]` to your application layout header, because you have separate JS applications on different controllers but with same basic layout, you will be quite annoyed with this. Quick way to get over this and continue work (but maybe not a final solution) with all assets precompiled is to add the following to the /config/initializers/assets.rb:

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += [/.*\.js/,/.*\.css/]
```

Note that this is as it is even for `.js.coffee` and `.css.scss`, `.js` and `.css` are enough.

Comment: Thanks! Really great solution. I wonder why it is not used by default in sprockets?

Comment: @Dimitry, it is because the whole idea of precompilation is to include all the files you need for certain purpose into one file. So only your 'top level' files should be included in this list, and they should use `//= require...` directives to include into themselves what they need. My solution above helps in development, but if you do something like `rake assets:precompile` you would end up with a huge mess of files that never need to be served. For example, if you have an Angular project where each directive/controller/template is a separate file, you can easily have 100+ files...

Answer (score 5):

Ideally, the solution by @zmilojko works but I also have active admin in this app.. hence after looking a little further I found the following solution:

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w(*.svg *.eot *.woff *.ttf *.gif *.png *.ico)
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile << /\A(?!active_admin).*\.(js|css)\z/
```

Just add the lines above to: /config/initializers/assets.rb

The code above precompiles assets while skipping active admin files. so that they are not processed twice or out of turn leading to errors.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, reading the error on the browser, all I did was add the following line of code:

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( depot.css )
```

To the /config/initializers/assets.rb file and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You may detele `<%= javascript_include_tag 'xxx' %>` from your erb, and in you `assets/javascript/name_space/index.js.coffee` , append this

```
#= require ./xxx
```